# Follow-up Comments Notification Without a Plug-in

Tags: comments, notifications

I'm trying to find the code to insert in my Comments.php to add the functionality of "Follow-up Comments Notification" but I can't find it.

I can't use a plug-in because it's for a theme that I'm starting to develop for a client and he doesn't want to use plug-ins. I know there has to be a way because I've been told that some themes come with that feature but I don't seem to understand where that piece of code is.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple, just hook a function on `comment_post` in which you check if the comment is a reply and send the author of the parent comment an email:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'notify_author_of_reply', 10, 2);

function notify_author_of_reply($comment_id, $approved){
  if($approved){
    $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
    if($comment->comment_parent){
      $parent_comment = get_comment($comment->comment_parent);
      wp_mail($parent_comment->comment_author_email, 'Hello', 'Dude you got a reply...');
    }
  }
}
```

For handling unsubscriptions, you can add store emails of people who don't want notifications inside an option (and check if `$parent_comment->comment_author_email` is not within that list in the function above).

Comment: Wow! One Trick Pony, thanks for your reply. I'll jump to my theme and test your code. :-)

Comment: I was finally able to test this code and IT WORKS! Thanks again for your help! :-) It took me some time because I was using and old Comments.php and it didn't have a "Reply" function, so I had to change that first. I have a new question, is there a way to get a link to the Post of the comment in the body of the Email Notification?

Comment: yes, use `get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID);`

Comment: I'm unable to make it work, but only because I don't know where to place that extra line of code. Could you be more specific? I have no knowledge of PHP so I'm doing it in the "Trial and Error" way but of all the combinations I've tried so far I can't get the link to show up :( Thanks, again!

Comment: Ok, I tried placing that code everywhere with no luck. I took a look at the wp_mail function and I was able to change the name and email of the "Sender" using $headers BUT I still can't get the link of the Post to the body of my notification email. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It's wild how WordPress has created / we live in a world where one can develop a theme for a client with no knowledge of PHP!